# Heroku Rails API can take 15 seconds to respond but shows fast runtime in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, heroku

I have a Rails API hosted with Heroku that seems to work fine most of the time, but occasionally takes up to 20 seconds to respond to a request for information.

The response message states that the server runtime is just 300 ms (and this has been proved by looking at the heroku metrics).  We're also look at the Request Queue Time on the metrics and this doesn't indicate any reason for the long delay.

We don't think that it is because the dyno has unloaded, because just prior to this message we performed a log in and also a GET request on another data field.

It may have something to do with our internet connection, which occasionally performs slowly.  But we can't prove this because it doesn't happen consistently enough.

Any advice on what to investigate would be greatly appreciated.